# Why do gravity and electricity sometimes obey inverse square laws over the same distance scale?

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity, coulombs-law, virtual-particles, carrier-particles

Is this a chance mathematical coincidence or is there a good physical explanation for it?

Comment: related questions/possible duplicates (of the title question): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47084/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11284/50583. It is not clear to me how you arrive at the question in the body - why would two things obeying the same force law mean that their force carriers can decay into each other?

Comment: "Does this mean for example that spin 2 gravitons can decay to spin 1 virtual photons sometimes?" No, if this happened, the reason would certainly not be because both "obey inverse square laws."

Comment: I am pretty sure gravity is not mediated by any particle I think the correct interpretation of quantum gravity is some form of Quantum Loop Gravity.

Comment: @hft I have edited the question body now

Comment: @Cerise I have edited the question body now

Answer (score 7):

The modern point of view is that we should understand field theories as *effective field theories*, or *low energy* approximations of more complete theories. Because of the uncertainty principle, "low energy" also means "long distance", which means that derivatives of the field will tend to be small (compared to the scale at which the low energy approximation breaks down).

Lorentz invariance also seems to be a fundamental symmetry of Nature, as far as we can tell. (Meaning that special relativity is a good approximation when gravitational fields are weak).

Therefore, the simplest option for a relativistic equation for the field, that has some derivatives (allowing for things to change in space and time), but not more derivatives (which would be "higher order" in an effective field theory expansion and would also lead to issues like an [Ostragradsky instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrogradsky_instability), and is *linear in the field* (which is a good approximation if the fields aren't too strong), will schematically take the form

$$
\partial_t^2 \phi - \nabla^2 \phi = J
$$
where $J$ is a source for the field $\phi$, and I've suppressed indices that might appear for a spin-1 or spin-2 field, which aren't important for this discussion. You can also have a mass term consistent with the arguments I've made above, but since the photon and graviton are massless as far as anyone knows, I've suppressed this subtlety.

In the non-relativistic limit, we can ignore the time derivatives, and the equation becomes Laplace's equation

$$
\nabla^2 \phi = \rho
$$
where $\rho = - J$. If we take a point particle for $\rho$, then the solution of this equation (that does not blow up at spatial infinity) is
$$
\phi \propto \frac{1}{r}
$$
and the force (or derivative of the potential) follows the inverse square law
$$
F \propto \nabla \phi \propto \frac{1}{r^2}
$$
So you can see that the inverse square law follows as a natural consequence of very general properties we expect physical theories to have.

The weak interactions avoid this argument because of the mass term, which I could have included above, but chose not to. The $W$ and $Z$ bosons have a mass (due to the Higgs mechanism), which leads to a Yukawa suppression of the force.

The strong interactions avoid this argument because at low energies it is not a good approximation to ignore the interaction terms (non-linear terms) that I assumed were small above. The interaction terms lead to confinement. At energies much below the confinement scale, the strong interaction is effectively mediated by pions, which (like the $W$ and $Z$ bosons) have a mass, which limits the range of the force.

Incidentally, in $d$ spatial dimensions (at least for $d\neq 2$), the solution to Laplace's equation (that does not blow up at spatial infinity) is
$$
\phi \propto \frac{1}{r^{d-2}}
$$
and the force is
$$
F \propto \frac{1}{r^{d-1}}
$$
This is why you sometimes see people say that the inverse square law holds in 3 spatial dimensions; the solutions of Laplace's equation naturally give you an inverse square law in 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

To get an idea as to why it helps to think about field lines.  If you imagine a sphere enclosing an electric charge or mass then the number of field lines coming into or out of the sphere depends only on the amount of charge or mass inside.  Given this the density of the field lines is inversely proportional to the surface area of the sphere, and since the surface area of a sphere is proportional to the radius squared the density of the field lines is inversely proportional to the radius squared.  If you think of both objects exerting a force on each other for every instance that they intersect each others field lines then you get that the force is inversely proportional to their distance squared.

Comment: When the  force becomes stronger than  1/ r^2  you need to add field lines.So the picture you give could involve successive spherical surfaces with the field lines being more numerous for smaller spheres at smaller distances. Field lines would have to at least double in number so the force is equal in all directions.

Comment: Nice answer, and Andrew's answer says why the field lines behave like that.

Comment: @Adrdav22 But you can't just add field lines. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem

Comment: @PM 2Ring I get the point you are making. But I was pointing out that the surface integral is only a good approximation for relatively long distance scales.At short distances quantum field theory will invalidate the surface integral when the electric potential no longer depends simply on 1/r. So I was just proposing an improvised  pictorial way to compensate for the shift in dependency on 1/r. – 
Adrdav22
 27 mins ago   Delete

Answer (score -4):

The potential for every fundamental force is the Yukawa potential:$V(r) = -g^{2}\frac{e^{-amr}}{r}$.Since we assume that both the photon and graviton have 0 mass then it becomes $-g^{2}\frac{1}{r}$.Since $F = a\frac{dV}{dr}\rightarrow F=ag^{2}\frac{1}{r^{2}}$

Comment: If you dont want to comment on where I am wrong , dont downvote.I accept criticism as long as it is justified.

Comment: The objection is the blatantly incorrect statement that “the potential for every force is the Yukawa potential.” It is easy to find example situations not mediated by the Yukawa potential, though it is of great importance in theoretical physics.

Comment: @MattHanson Such as?

Comment: A harmonic oscillator…?

Comment: A harmonic oscillator is not a fundamental force.Editted.

Comment: I think the Ops question can be interpreted as, "Why do interactions have the relationship to distance that they do?", whether they are in the form of a force, potential energy, or spacetime curvature, in which case even though the Yukawa potential is more fundamental than the inverse square law for forces the OP could still be thinking, "Why is the Yukawa potential $V(r)\propto\frac{e^{-amr}}{r}$?"

Comment: @AndersGustafson I dont think you can answer this.If we could then we would know so much more about the universe.

Comment: @ACuriousMind. I have edited the question body now

Comment: It's true that spin 0, 1, and 2 particles have a potential that kind of looks like this, but it's not true that that exact expression applies to any pair of particles subject to any fundamental force. For one thing the minus sign changes for spin 1. For another thing it should be $q_1q_2$ instead of $g^2$ for spin 1. And the effect of the weak force isn't really ever written as a potential because that's just not what it does in our universe. Finally what about the strong force? -  because of the confinement property and because there are 3 kinds of charges this equation isn't even close.

Comment: @AXensen a can b negative